# compile workrave from source

Tags: compiling

How do I install workrave from source?

I cloned the source from github:

```
git clone https://github.com/rcaelers/workrave.git
cd workrave
```

there is an INSTALL file which sais, I should use `./configure; make; make install` but that seems outdated. There is no config file. I found out that I have to use `autogen.sh` boforehand:

```
sudo apt-get install autopoint intltool libxtst-dev glib-2.0 python-cheetah glibmm-2.4 gtkmm-2.4
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
```

This stops with those warnings:

```
In file included from UnixInputMonitorFactory.cc:38:0:
XScreenSaverMonitor.hh:27:38: fatal error: X11/extensions/scrnsaver.h: No such file or directory
 #include <X11/extensions/scrnsaver.h>
                                      ^
compilation terminated.
```

maybe I am missing some packages? How can I find out the needed packages and How do I compile it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find missing files with

```
apt-file update
apt-file find scrnsaver.h
```

Which results in

```
libxss-dev: /usr/include/X11/extensions/scrnsaver.h
```

You also need the debug symbols to that package that you will find with

```
apt-cache search libxtst|grep dbg
apt-cache search libxss|grep dbg
```

So this will be `libxtst6-dbg` and `libxss1-dbg`

so this works fine:

```
sudo apt-get install autopoint intltool libxtst-dev glib-2.0 python-cheetah \
             glibmm-2.4 gtkmm-2.4 libxss-dev libxtst6-dbg libxext6-dbg libxss1-dbg
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: The workrave initial configure passed, but still missing this header. After installing the missing packages as suggested by rubo77, redo config, then make was happy.

Comment: I still get errors such as "./configure: line 18329: syntax error near unexpected token `-Wno-cast-function-type,'" or "./configure: line 18329: `AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG(-Wno-cast-function-type,'": is the repository still up to date?

Comment: You should open an issue in the workrave GitHub issues